# split a large video into small pieces of videos (regardless of format) that can be dispersed on different storage spaces?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to write a algorithm to split a large video into small pieces of videos (regardless of format) that can be dispersed on different storage spaces? I am kind of new to this thing and I just want it for learning purpose. I have achieved this to some extent by Python and OpenCV but that converts the video to different frames. Can someone help?

Comment: That's a little broad. Should the chunks still be playable?

Comment: Yes, if I can find a way to split it then surely i will find a way to combine them.

Comment: I suggest looking into ffmpeg, (the console utility). Python seems like a wrong tool for the job...